# Facebook comment -> blog article comments

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I'm trying to automatically embed Facebook comments on my page to my blog.

I mean, if a person posts a comment on an article on my Facebook page, I want this comment to be posted on my site, inside the article page (same article).

How can I do that? I'm trying, but no success.

It's a WordPress site: http://www.smokebuddies.com.br/

My Facebook page: facebook.com/SmokeBuddies/

Here's what I need, highlighted in red: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOG8I.jpg

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @CBroe
I tried adding the facebook comment plugin, both by the wordpress plugin, and by the plugin provided by facebook itself. As you can see, the facebook comments box appears on my site, but the functionality of posting to facebook and the comment appearing on the site, still does not work. I also do not know if this functionality is related to the facebook comments plugin.

Comment: So what you want is called Comment Mirroring, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

Answer (score 1):

I managed to settle here after a lot of fighting, the flow and the following:

1. Create your facebook app with any name;
2. configure the same for an application of a site and become the same public;
3. In the app's platform configuration, select 'site';
4. Insert the meta tag

   ```
   <meta property = "fb: app_id" content = "(your app id)">
   ```

   before the head is closed;
5. Insert jdk shortly after opening body:

   ```
   <div id = "fb-root"> </ div>
   <script> (function (d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName (s) [0];
   if (d.getElementById (id)) return;
   js = d.createElement (s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=(your app id)";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore (js, fjs);
   } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); </ script>
   ```
6. Insert a tag in the location that you want to appear in the comments box:

   ```
   <div class="fb-comments" data-href="" data-numposts="8" data-width="100%"></div>
   ```
7. In the comment moderation setting, click on creating and active comment mirroring or mirrored comments, something like this. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

At that time, the comments are already looking like mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

You can iframe embed a Facebook Post or a Single Comment, OR add a unique Comment Thread to your site by enabling Facebook SDK (adding some javascript to your wordpress site) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

I created a custom plugin for wordpress that turns the SDK on and wrote this guide to help users embed Facebook content into their post.
http://aurora.uconn.edu/2017/08/08/facebook/

Comment: I know that you can embed some comments, but then I need to copy the iframe of each comment and paste on my code, but what I want is to automatically post the comment on the site...

Here's what I need, highlited in red : https://imgur.com/a/wNF7Z